# Is there an API to monitor data changement in ArangoJS, like LIVE QUERY in OrientJS/OrientDB?

Tags: arangodb

We are comparing between ArangoDB and OrientDB for a new project.

For our users, notification(of task and data modification) is important. So I like the LIVE QUERY of OrientDB. What is the solution in ArangoDB?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such API in ArangoDB.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn’t an api for this out of the box, this could be built either via the Foxx services or using similar to [arangochair](https://github.com/baslr/arangochair)

The bigger question though is wether you would want the dB to track the changes or leave that to the app server. For example GraphQL has a very nice subscription model to track changes. You probably want to consider if you do need the DB to spend precious CPU cycles tracking who knows how many items or can it be left to the app server? 
Additionally, implementing the tracking on the app server frees your application from being tied directly to a specific dB.

In the end, it really depends on your app requirements, but I think there are more important evaluation criteria when comparing databases (performance , scalability, ease of use, etc, just to name a few).

Comment: Yes I will keep in mind what you said in my evaluation. Thanks a lot!